# SQLITE: Getting difference from two different column values

Tags: sqlite, sum

I have 2 tables naming..InvoiceGarmentService and Payment..

```
InvoiceGarmentService Table Data
----------------------------------
IGSID     InvoiceID   Price

0           1001      50

1           1001      100

2           1002      500

3           1002      600

------------------------------------
Payment Data
------------------------------------
PaymentID InvoiceID Amount

0          1001      20

1          1002      300

2          1003      900

------------------------------------
```

I want to get the due amount ie. `(Sum of Price From IGS)-(Sum of Amount from Payment)`
I have used a query like this

```
SELECT sum(Price) FROM InvoiceGarmentService - sum(Amount)FROM Payment 
WHERE InvoiceGarmentService.InvoiceID='1001'
```

But I am Unable to find result..saying here is a syntax error but I dn knw about that..
Anyone can help me

Comment: Seeing your query, i would advise you to read the 'sql-basics' first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT igs.InvoiceID, (val1 - val2)
  FROM (SELECT InvoiceID, sum(Price) AS val1
          FROM InvoiceGarmentService
         GROUP BY InvoiceID) igs
  JOIN (SELECT InvoiceID, sum(Amount) AS val2
          FROM Payment
         GROUP BY InvoiceID) p
    ON (igs.InvoiceID = p.InvoiceID)
 WHERE igs.InvoiceID = '1001'
```